# Individual page styling with $

Tags: html, css, joomla, styles

I have a page with `www.something.com/home` ( and the background is red, because i used this styling)

```
body.menu-home .main-bg {
background: red ; }
```

but when people go to for example `www.something.com/home/photos` the styling is also red, because it follows the styling the /home . How can I change this? I just want the red background to be only on /home.

I tried doing this

```
body.menu-home$ .main-bg {
background: red ; }
```

but it didnt work, any suggestions? Im using joomla btw

Thank You in advance

Comment: i dont believe you can use `$` signs to style css you should add a class to the body based on the paged visited, ie: body.home or body.photos, etc

Comment: You are absolutely confusing a lot of things here... css styles do not apply across different pages. Nor do URL and dom-tree correlate in any way. Also the subject operator is not supported by any browser at the moment. It is specified in CSS Selectors level 4 with `!` atm, but that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Cristoph Well since the OP most probable has an external stylesheet of course the styles applies to different pages. But still adding a class would do it. Or use inline styles for the specific page.

Comment: @jtheman That is just an assupmtion you make;) You do not have any evidence for that. Maybe it's an inline-style reappearing in every sub-page? Without knowing the structure you can't possibly tell. Also having a css file does not make it magically appear on a html page. And btw. I'm Christoph.

Comment: @Cristoph Yes it's an assuption (I wrote "most probable") but as the OP get the result (red background) on other pages then why should your comment ("css styles do not apply across different pages") have any validity? Also from a little experience with Joomla an external CSS is "most probable"

Comment: @jtheman Dude, no need to take my trollpost serious. It was just a sarcastic comment to the poorly written question. And my name ist still C*h*ristoph.

Answer (score 1):

You could always add something like this to your template index.php file:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        $css = 'body.menu-home .main-bg {'
              .'background: red;'
              .'}';
        $doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);
}
```

It detects of your site is on the default menu item, which I assume is your homepage, and if so, add in that CSS code.

Note: If `$doc = JFactory::getDocument();` has already been defined, remove it from the code above

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 missing a `$css =` however?

Comment: @Christoph - thanks for pointing that out :) Need to make myself another coffee I see :/